# Find natural (arc length) parametrization of a curve.

Tags: differential-geometry, polar-coordinates, parametric, arc-length

If a curve is defined like this:
$$
\rho = 1 - \cos(x)
$$
find natural parametrization of it.

So this is how the curve looks like when when I use polar coordinates $x = \rho \cos(t)$, $y = \rho\sin(t)$:
$$
\alpha(t) = \bigl((1 - \cos(t)) \cos(t), (1 - \cos(t)) \sin(t)\bigr).
$$

Now I found natural parameter to be $s = 4 \arcsin(\sqrt{s/8})$.

Can anyone tell me if this is good?
How does my curve look alike when I plug natural parameter in it?
Am I doing something wrong?
Sorry for the bad post. :/

Comment: What does "natural parametrization" mean? Cartesian coordiantes or what?

Comment: It means that the norm of the tangent vector is equal to 1.

Comment: Check out this Math SX question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/751781/how-to-parametrize-a-curve-by-its-arc-length

Comment: Your curve ill look exactly the same, but the speed of drawing is now totally uniformized: the time for the draw is proportional to the length having been drawn.

Comment: That wasn't my question, but thanks anyway. Maybe I wasn't clear. I don't know how to plug my new parameter, in this case s, back in the starting curve equation.. I don't know how to calculate ((1 - cos(s))cos(s), (1 - cos(s))sin(s)) , s being 4arcsine(sqrt(s/8)) :)

Comment: @Ross: $\sin(\arcsin t) = t$ and $\cos(\arcsin t) = \sqrt{1 - t^{2}}$ for $-1 \leq t \leq 1$; does that help?

Comment: Your equation for the natural parameter $s$ contains an $s$ on both sides of the equation.

Comment: I believe that equation should be $t=$ not $s=$.

Comment: I'm confused by your use of *natural parameterization*. Do you mean to express the curve given by $\rho=1-\cos\theta$ in  the *natural (or intrinsic) equation*? That is, one that is independent of any coordinate system. If so, then I can help you.

Comment: @CyeWaldman  He means to express the parameterization in terms of arclength $s=\int_0^t\Vert \mathbf{r}^\prime(u)\Vert\,du$.

Comment: @Andrew D. Hwang I know that too. The problem I am facing here is how to calculate (1 - cos(4arcsinsqrt(s/8)))cos(4arcsinsqrt(s/8)), (1 - cos(4arcsinsqrt(s/8))sin(4arcsinsqrt(s/8))). I need to find that so that I could continue calculating N, B, curvature, torsion. Do you understand me now?

Comment: In case it's of future use, there are also identities expressing $\cos(4t)$ and $\sin(4t)$ in terms of $\cos t$ and $\sin t$: Apply the double-angle formulas twice, or use the binomial theorem to expand$$\cos(4t) + i\sin(4t) = e^{4it} = (e^{it})^{4} =  (\cos t + i\sin t)^{4}.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The polar graph $\rho = f(\theta)$ parametrized by
$$
(x, y) = \bigl(f(t)\cos t, f(t) \sin t\bigr)
\tag{1}
$$
has speed
$$
\frac{ds}{dt} = \sqrt{f(t)^{2} + f'(t)^{2}}.
$$
For $f(t) = 1 - \cos t$, the speed is
$$
\sqrt{(1 - \cos t)^{2} + (\sin t)^{2}}
= \sqrt{2(1 - \cos t)}
= 2|\sin \tfrac{t}{2}|.
$$
If $0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$, then $\sin \frac{t}{2}$ is non-negative, so the arclength function is
$$
s = \int_{0}^{t} 2\sin \tfrac{u}{2}\, du
= 4(1 - \cos \tfrac{t}{2}),
$$
or $t = 2\arccos(1 - \frac{s}{4})$.

The double-angle formulas for the circular functions read
\begin{align*}
  \cos(2\theta) &= \cos^{2}\theta - \sin^{2}\theta, \\
  \sin(2\theta) &= 2\sin\theta \cos\theta,
\end{align*}
and $\cos(\arccos u) = u$ while $\sin(\arccos u) = \sqrt{1 - u^{2}}$.

Substituting $\theta = \arccos(1 - \frac{s}{4})$ gives
$$
\left.
\begin{aligned}
  \cos t &= (1 - \tfrac{s}{4})^{2} - 1 + (1 - \tfrac{s}{4})^{2}
  = 2(1 - \tfrac{s}{4})^{2} - 1, \\
  \sin t &= 2(1 - \tfrac{s}{4}) \sqrt{1 - (1 - \tfrac{s}{4})^{2}}
  = 2(1 - \tfrac{s}{4})\sqrt{\tfrac{s}{4}(2 - \tfrac{s}{4})}.
\end{aligned}
\right\}
\tag{2}
$$

The arc length parametrization is found by substituting (2) into (1). As a numerical check, the diagram shows the trig parametrization (red) overlaid by the putative arc length parametrization (blue).

[image: Polar and arc-length parametrizations of a cardioid]