How should I keep arc length equal between multiple points on a parametric curve?
I made this thing in desmos:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/na9sehjskk
The distance between points changes depending on the speed of the points. Is there a way to keep the distance between them equal at all times?
I tried changing the difference between a and b, b and c etc. so that when their speed increases, the difference decreases, but this only decreased the problem a bit, and the last few points usually went backward when the first points slowed down.
Was my original approach correct and I just need to fine-tune it, or is there a different, better way to do it?
To clarify, I made a parametric equation, then a point that follows that equation as 'a' changes. Then I made another point that does the same thing as 'b' changes. I repeated this a couple of times
a,b,c are variables, and b=a+0.05, c=b+0.05 etc.
Because $\sqrt{(dx/dt)^2+(dy/dt)^2}$ isn't constant, these points spread apart as each point has a different speed from the other at the same time
I want a way to keep the arclength the same between every point.
Edit:
I don't really understand what the linked posts mean, but I did figure out a method of approximation by using the osculating circle at each point. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/n7u0evif9s
This uses the equation for the arc length of a parametric circle, the equation for the radius of the osculating circle to the curve at any point, and a lot of points to keep the arc length equal between points.
all the other changes were for simplicity or to hide the fact that this is an approximation,

+1 because this animation is fun to watch. But can you please explain the problem here in mathematical terms, for those of us not very familiar with Desmos.

The usual method is to parameterize with respect to arclength by taking $l(r) = \int_{-3}^r \sqrt{(dx/dt)^2+(dy/dt)^2} , dt$ and then take $x(l^{-1}(s+d)), y(l^{-1}(s+d))$ for $d = 0, 0.05, 0.1$ (or whatever you wish.) But generally speaking arclength is not possible to find analytically, so you will probably need to numerically integrate and numerically invert. I don't know how to do this in Desmos.

I have addressed this problem previously here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1371668/equation-to-place-points-equidistantly-on-an-archimedian-spiral-using-arc-length/2216736#2216736, and here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2375940/parametric-curves-with-constant-length-differential/2376794#2376794.
