# Impossibility of parametrising a non-singular curve by arclength

Tags: differential-geometry

Why can't you parametrise a nonsingular curve by its arclength?

Is it simply because the following arclength doesn't exist where $\alpha '(t) =0$?

$$s(t) = \int_{t_0}^{t} |\alpha '(t)| dt$$
Thanks.

Comment: Whats the definition of non regular ?

Comment: More specifically I'm referring to parametrised differentiable curves that are not regular at all points, hence the first derivative of the curve, $\alpha ' (t) $ is zero at some points of t, where $\alpha : I \rightarrow R^n$,$ t \in I$ (interval).

Comment: I think the parameterization, is $\alpha\circ s^{-1}$ and this wont be differentiable cause you have to divide by zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/751839), you can see that in order to get $\lvert \beta'(t) \rvert =1$ it is necessary to divide by $\alpha'(t)$ for each $t\in I$...

Alternatively,  $\frac {dt}{ds}$ needs to exist for each $t$ in the domain of the curve.